# Connect Two sets of 5 meter RGB Lights

Tags: wiring, led

I bought two of these [RGB led strips](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00CD2GZFM/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o02_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) of 5 meters and would like to connect them together. Is is possible to do this with the power supply I have or would I need something stronger or maybe an amplifier?

Comment: Do you want to control the LED strips separately or together?

Comment: Coincidentally I installed two of these strips in my daughter's bedroom this week. The kit came with a dual power plug and runs off one power supply. I suggest you do an exchange for [the right product](https://www.amazon.co.uk/CGN-Waterproof-Compatible-Assistant-Decoration/dp/B084KZGGMG/ref=psdc_3764800031_t3_B07P9PX83B) for your needs. LED strips can usually be linked, but you need more current than what that power supply will provide.

Comment: [This product](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B08F75DNZ6/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_awdb_imm_t1_kQj8Fb5CHG380) might be better.

Answer (score 0):

If both 5 meters strips came with one ac adapter each, you can connect the strips together, and put one ac at the start of the strip and the other ac adapter in the middle (where you connect the two strips together).

That amazon link shows:

- LED voltage 12V
- Wattage: 24W
- Power Supply: AC/DC ADAPTOR INPUT 100-240V; OUTPUT 12V 3.0A

the adapter gives you up to 3 amps, but each strip can use 2A, (24w / 12V = 2Amps)

The adapter can (and most of the time should) give you more amps than what you need, the strip will decide how much it will draw from the adapter, so amps won't burn the strip.

Or you could buy a single adapter that is 12v,  6 Amps (or higher, but has to be 12 v).

Hope this helps.